# Is it possible for google chrome extension to access google drive with javascript?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

I want to make an extension which will work with a google sheets file in my google drive (to save some data).

But then anyone, after installing the extension from google store, can edit the script locally to mess with my google drive.

Comment: Drive OAuth doesn't provide fine grained, row level permissions, so yes in theory somebody could overwrite data they aren't supposed to. The only solution is to write a service that filters updates rather than allow the extension direct write access.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you could take a look at [Google Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk#create_and_open_files_directly_from_the_drive_ui)